# How to scan numbers of order 10^20 or greater in a c program? And how to find sum of digits of squares of numbers > 10^20?

Tags: c, data-structures

And how to find sum of digits of squares of numbers > 10^20?

Comment: Can you give more context to your problem ? It sounds like you're not supposed to actually perform the squaring, there must be some mathematical "trick".

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use a library for big integers, such as [GNU MP](http://gmplib.org/) for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a bignum library such as [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/). It has [formatted input functions](http://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Input.html#Formatted-Input).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need full precision you can use the `float` or `double` types.